# How to write a self expanding code in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a self-expanding code. I need it for my telegram-bot. Basically it should get an if condition and an outcome from a user. Outcomes are a bit more complicated than print(n) but it will work even in this case. I can't figure out a way to write it properly.

I thought in this way:

```
def program():
    inp=input()
    if inp == cond1:
        print(outc1)
    else:
        print("unknown command")
def setup1():
    global cond1
    global outc1
    cond1=input("Please type in your condition: ")
    outc1=input("Please type in your outcome: ")
while True:
    command = input()
    if command == 'setup1':
        setup1()
    elif command == 'program':
        program()
    else:
        print("unknown command")
```

This is a really rough example but it represents the idea. So my question is **how to do this idea more beautiful** and **how to make more conditions and outcomes without actually spamming defs for each one?**. I know that it might be harmful for me if any user will be able to add lines in a running code but the point is that any additions will only print back because I’m only taking strings from users and not executing them. I need this function to expand administrative opportunities for this bot’s future owners. For example I might set a password for this function and that’s it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "self-writing code", but this isn't it.  What you DO need is a list of commands:

```
commands = {
    'program': program,
    'setup1': setup1
}

while True:
    command = input()
    if command in commands:
        commands[command]()
    else:
        print("unknown command")
```

Comment: Technically, it's a *dict* of commands :)

Comment: Nah, you didn’t get the point. I wanted to make users able to write their own commands without any script knowledge. You can run my code and probably realize what I’m talking about. In my code you can write setup1 to specify condition and outcome and execute it with typing “program” and then answer to your condition will be your outcome. And I wanted to create multiple commands.

Comment: That's a horrible idea, because some user is immediately going to do `os.system( 'rm -rf /*' )` and kill your computer.